# Would combining light and dark overlay keep the image the same?

Tags: color, transparency, color-theory, overlay

If you have an image, and you added an overlay of a semi-transparent white, e.g. `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)` in CSS, you get a slightly lighter version of the image.

My question is, if you add another overlay on top of it (with another element or something) and that element has `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)`, which is semi-transparent black with the same opacity, would the image turn back to normal?

Comment: wouldn't that just give you an overlay of `(rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.3)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Color = alpha*FG + (1-alpha)*BG

what you are proposing is

Color = alpha + (1- alpha)*(0+(1-beta)*original)

so alpha would have to be

(0.3 original)/(-1. + 0.7 original)

if first layer is 0.3. So no not possible unless you only have one color. Even if this wasnt the case you would lose all pure colors by clipping.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to use overlays and get the image's true colors back?